# How to find the coordinates of all internal edges of a 3D mesh?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, 3d, coordinates, edges

I have a 3D image with dimensions specified, and with the code as follows:

```
% input image
imageSizeY = 30;
imageSizeX = 20;
imageSizeZ = 5;

% obtain size of internal vertices
ny = imageSizeY - 1;
nx = imageSizeX - 1;
nz = imageSizeZ - 1;

% generate 3D mesh (image coordinate system)
[columnsInImage, rowsInImage, pagesInImage] = meshgrid(1:nx, 1:ny, 1:nz);

% obtain coordinates of vertices
vertexCoords = [rowsInImage(:), columnsInImage(:), pagesInImage(:)];

% obtain count of vertices (from top to bottom)
countVertex= ny*(vertexCoords(:,2) - 1) + vertexCoords(:,1) + ny*nx*(vertexCoords(:,3)-1);
```

[image]

In the attached image, the internal vertices are marked dots while the edges are marked `x`

I have been able to find the coordinates of all the internal vertices (from top to bottom) of the image as shown in the code. I however will need to find the coordinates of all edges but I am not sure I know exactly how to go about achieving this.

[Recent figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ahYfJ.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because it's a regular grid, I used logical operations on the coordinates to find their min's and max's:

```
% deal vertexes into xyz coordinates
[y,x,z] = deal(vertexCoords(:,1),vertexCoords(:,2),vertexCoords(:,3));
nv = numel(x); % number of vertexes
allV = (1:nv).'; % indexes of all vertexes
% compute cube edges indexes => edge = [point1,point2]
edgeIdxs1 = [allV(y < ny),allV(y < ny) + 1];
edgeIdxs2 = [allV(x < nx),allV(x < nx) + ny];
edgeIdxs3 = [allV(z < nz),allV(z < nz) + ny*nx];
edgeIdxs = [edgeIdxs1;edgeIdxs2;edgeIdxs3];
% xyz coordinates of the edges
xEdges = [x(edgeIdxs(:,1)),x(edgeIdxs(:,2))];
yEdges = [y(edgeIdxs(:,1)),y(edgeIdxs(:,2))];
zEdges = [z(edgeIdxs(:,1)),z(edgeIdxs(:,2))];
% "outer" edges (as defined by you) 
outerEdges = all(xEdges == nx,2) | all(xEdges == 1,2) ...
    | all(yEdges == ny,2) | all(yEdges == 1,2) ...
    | all(zEdges == nz,2) | all(zEdges == 1,2);
% "inner" edges indexes
innerEdges = ~outerEdges;
innerEdgeIdxs = edgeIdxs(innerEdges,:);
% xyz coordinates of the inner edges (to plot x on their middle)
xInnerEdges = [x(innerEdgeIdxs(:,1)),x(innerEdgeIdxs(:,2))];
yInnerEdges = [y(innerEdgeIdxs(:,1)),y(innerEdgeIdxs(:,2))];
zInnerEdges = [z(innerEdgeIdxs(:,1)),z(innerEdgeIdxs(:,2))];
% "outer" vertexes indexes
outerVertexes = (x == nx | x == 1) | (y == ny | y == 1) | (z == nz | z == 1);
% "inner" vertexes indexes (to plot o on them)
innerVertexes = ~outerVertexes;
% plot all edges
plot3([x(edgeIdxs(:,1)),x(edgeIdxs(:,2))]',...
    [y(edgeIdxs(:,1)),y(edgeIdxs(:,2))]',...
    [z(edgeIdxs(:,1)),z(edgeIdxs(:,2))]','k');
hold on
% plot x's
plot3(mean(xInnerEdges,2),mean(yInnerEdges,2),mean(zInnerEdges,2),'xr');
% plot o's
plot3(x(innerVertexes),y(innerVertexes),z(innerVertexes),'oc');
axis equal
xlabel('x');ylabel('y');zlabel('z');
```

this is an example with:

```
% input image
imageSizeY = 5;
imageSizeX = 5;
imageSizeZ = 5;
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @user2999345. I just realized i made a mistake in my diagram. Please, see the new figure attached. I am sorry about this. Many thanks for your time.

Comment: Please can you also help me out with `countEdge` (equivalent of the `countVertex`). Thank you so much!

Comment: I can't see the difference in this with this figure, is it the sketched axes? if so you can rotate the figure to be aligned with the desired output. I don't understand what `countVertex` is (neither `countEdge`) and I don't think they are mean something here, I think you should ask that in another question.

Comment: There is a difference in terms of where the edges begin. I think i have found a simple solution to this. Well except for the `countEdge`

Comment: I'm so, so sorry, please, pardon my ignorance yesterday. I realize you were correct although this made sense to me only after I have toiled with my approach. The part I don't understand in your code now is the xEdges, yEdges, and zEdges. Why are they  mx2 matrices? aren't they supposed to have just one column? Thanks!

Comment: Oh yeah! i do get it now... those are coordinates of lines whose midpoints are the x,y,z coordinates of the edges; but these are however, not in a specific order. Is it possible to have them listed such that they are numbered across the `y-axis (i.e. top-down)`, or the `x-axis (i.e. left-right)`. As for the misunderstanding from the figure, i didn't notice the plot is within the range of 4 along each axes.  Sorry about that.